# Can be dispatch the request from one servlet to 2 or more than 2 jsp pages

Tags: jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

Can I dispatch the request from one Servlet to two or more than 2 jsp pages using **RequestDispatcher**. It is possible or not? If not,is there any solution to dispatch the request from one servlet to many jsp pages?

Comment: and why do you want to do that? The client will not be able to see the result of the 2 jsp's . Dont forget that you can call other classes from inside a jsp page to perform extra functions etc...

Comment: sir but i want to learn this thing. google not give the answer so i am asking here. i think there is no impossible keyword in java.So may be there is a solution for it.

Comment: You need to explain what problem you're trying to solve - the answer most likely isn't that you need to dispatch to 2 or more jsps

Comment: i have a servlet which fetch the data from database & i want to used this data in two jsp pages in my website, first home.jsp & second contact.jsp. So i want the solution. If there is no solution so i will create 2 servlet but both servlet perform same operations.So one servlet  for home.jsp & another one for contact.jsp. Now i think u r understand my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can include `any number of JSP'`s using `RequestDispatcher.include(..)`.

But, you can forward to `only one JSP` using `RequestDispatcher.forward(..)`.

You cannot dispatch multiple times using `Forward` because, doing `RequestDispatcher.forward(..)` will commit and close and the response.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access two jsp's from a single RequestDispatcher call. What you can do is propagate the request to a jsp that uses a RequestDispatcher to propagate the request to another jsp and so on.... But all this is done sequential y, NOT simultaneously.

Comment: but it cant work in my case i want to show the data in both jsp page at once. If i will dispatch request from one to another jsp page so how i will so my first jsp page.Sir i have explain my problem in the comment please read it & give me proper  answer